# Apache Pig 0.12.0 on Hue not preprocessing statements as expected

Tags: apache-pig, parameter-passing, amazon-emr, hue

I'm using Hue for PIG scripts on amazon EMR. [I am using the declare and default statements as mentioned in the documentation.](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/cont.html#Usage-N1058F)

I have some %default and %declare statements and it looks like they are 
not preprocessed within Hue. Therefore, although the parameters are defined 
in my script, the editor keeps popping in a parameter configuration window. If I leave the parameter blank, the job fails with an error.

**Sample Script**

```
%declare OUTPUT_FOLDER 'testingOutput01';

ts = LOAD 's3://testbucket1/input/testdata-00000.gz' USING PigStorage('\t');
STORE ts INTO 's3://testbucket1/$OUTPUT_FOLDER' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Upon execution, it shows the pop-up window asking for values for OUTPUT_FOLDER. If I leave it blank it fails with the following error:

```
2015-06-23 20:15:54,908 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main  - ERROR 2997:
Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParseException:
Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 12.
Was expecting one of:
<IDENTIFIER> ...
<OTHER> ...
<LITERAL> ...
<SHELLCMD> ...
```

Is that the expected behavior? Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Configuration details:

```
AMI version:3.7.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.4.0
Applications:Hive 0.13.1, Pig 0.12.0, Impala 1.2.4, Hue
```

The same behavior is seen with default instead of declare.

If you need any clarifications then please do comment on this question. I will update it as needed.

Comment: Hue is an absolute disaster.  I would try ssh-ing to the instance an running your pig script from the command line.  If it runs, then you'll know it is an issue with Hue.

Comment: Good idea. I will try it tomorrow and get back to you on the results. I hope it works. That way I know what's wrong.

Comment: Romain added an answers which confirms that this is a bug in Hue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hue does not support %declare with a default statement. It will be fixed with: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2508

The current temporary workaround is to put any value in the popup.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That helps to resolve it for now.